# Increase size of filesystem /dev/sdb1 after increasing the size of /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, filesystems

For the FS

df -kh /store
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdb1        50G   45G  1.9G  97% /store

I have increased the size of /dev/sdb by 20G and then added the space to /dev/sdb1 by 20G by deleting the partition and creating it again

sdb               8:16   0   70G  0 disk
└─sdb1            8:17   0   70G  0 part

However i am not sure how to make it visible in /store

pvresize gives the error as no physical volume found

It is a cloud VM
vgs or vgdisplay doesnot show any VG created as well

Output of fstab as below
/dev/sdb1 /store/ ext4 defaults 0 0

However i am not sure how to make it visible in /store

pvresize gives the error as no physical volume found

It is a cloud VM
vgs or vgdisplay doesnot show any VG created as well

Output of fstab as below
/dev/sdb1 /store/ ext4 defaults 0 0

Answer (score 0):

From the output you posted, I don't see any indication that the system is using LVM, rather the filesystem is directly on /dev/sdb1. So simply try `umount /store` followed by `resize2fs /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: You are right its directly mounted to /dev/sdb1. 
I have tried resize2fs and it gives me this error

resize2fs /dev/sdb1
resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

tried checking lsof /dev/sdb1 to see if some process is running , it doesnot give any result

Comment: Did you umount it? If it is not mounted, it should normally not be busy.

Comment: yes , tried all these commands after unmounting the FS

Comment: Any other pointers?